# injecting web service's method into managed bean

Tags: jakarta-ee

This WebService's method `getWsInfoByMethod` is correctly run using JUnit test. return `WsInfo` DTO

```
@Stateless
@WebService(serviceName = "WsMethodService")
public class WsMethodService implements WebServiceMethodLocal {
  @EJB
  private WebServiceMethodDao webServiceMethodDao;

  public WsMethodService() {
  }

  @Override
  @WebMethod(operationName = "getWsInfoByMethod")
  public WsInfo getWsInfoByMethod(@WebParam(name = "webMethodId") Long webMethodId) throws ServiceFault {
     System.out.println("webServiceMethodDao  " + webServiceMethodDao);
     return webServiceMethodDao.getWebServiceByMethod(webMethodId);
  }

}
```

Now I want to call this method in Managed Bean "WsFunction"

```
@Stateless
public class WsFunction  {
  @EJB
  private WsMethodService ws;

  private WsInfo getWsInfo(String webMethodId) throws ServiceFault{        
    System.out.println("ws " + ws);
    WsInfo wsi = ws.getWsInfoByMethod(Long.valueOf(webMethodId));
    return wsi;
  }
}
```

But `ws` is can not injecting:

```
***ws null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mn.interactive.module.meta.expression.function.WsFunction.getWsInfo(WsFunction.java:75);***
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Are you running it within a container (e.g. JBOss) or are you calling it directly? Because injection only happens if you have someone managing your components.

Answer (score 0):

Try @Inject instead of @EJB in the WsFunction call

Comment: I try but this is unconcernedly

Answer (score 0):

`WsMethodService` should be only used to be called outside. You should not inject it. If you want to use some of it's functionality then you need to abstract that part into separate service layer. Why you do not inject `WebServiceMethodDao` to `WsFunction` and call it?

In practice question of injection depends on application server, you do not specify what you are using. Also when you inject EJB you need refer to interface (`WebServiceMethodLocal`), not an implementation (`WsMethodService`).

Comment: Hi win_wave, I use a GlassFish 4.0 application server. Then I try to inject WebServiceMethodDao : ---> public class WsFunction extends Function {

    @EJB
    private WebServiceMethodDao dao;

    public WsFunction() {
        super("ws");
    }

    private WsInfo getWsInfo(String webMethodId) throws ServiceFault {
        System.out.println("dao " + dao);
        WsInfo wsi = dao.getWebServiceByMethod(Long.valueOf(webMethodId));
        return wsi;
    }

}

Comment: But dao is null in this time, then Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at mn.interactive.module.meta.expression.function.WsFunction.getWsInfo(WsFunction.java:74) How to I inject WebServiceMethodDao? And how do refer to interface WebServiceMethodLocal

Comment: Is anywhere else injecting works? It could be so that you are doing something initially wrong, which results in that. In general GF should try to resolve dependencies when you deploy application, and do not have null pointer exceptions. Try to use `@Inject` instead of `@EJB` and reply what are results.